# how to write lex file for input like "{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}"

Tags: json, parsing, racket, tokenize, lex

I want to implement a json parser, but having problem with parse object like "{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}",  currently the parser output somthing like this

```
'(json
  (object
   "{"
   (kvpair
    "\"a\":1,\"b\""
    ":"
    (json (number "2")))
   "}"))
```

but what i actually want is

```
'(json
    (object
     "{"
     (kvpair "\"a\"" ":" (json (number "1")))
     ","
     (kvpair "\"b\"" ":" (json (number "2")))
     "}"))
```

I am using #lang ragg and parser-tools/lex, so how can i write the lex rules so i can get the right output.
[source_code](http://pastebin.com/qHcXiDu0)

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: JFYI, you know there is an existing JSON parser built into racket, right?

Comment: yes, i just do it for fun.@JohnClements

Comment: I define the lex like this `   [string-literal (token 'STRING lexeme)]
   [punctuator lexeme]` , and punctuator including "{" "}" "[" "]" "," ":". I don't know how to do so that when comes string,the lex will not choose the longest match, but will stop at "\"a\"", @soegaard

Comment: @somethin Is it possible for you to post the entire grammar?

Comment: The usual way to do this with `lex` is using *states*.  However the documentation for [parser-tools/lex](http://docs.racket-lang.org/parser-tools/Lexers.html) does not mention states.  If you do not have that, then it is still possible to write an application that inspects the tokens returned by the lexer, and emits the whitespace as you request.  But a complete working example is a good place to start.

Comment: @soegaard   ok, I put it here: http://pastebin.com/qHcXiDu0, I am using the grammer from ragg document:   http://hashcollision.org/ragg  I am writing this just for learn the lexing and parsing.

Comment: do you mean somehow I should identify the string in the object or not?  @ThomasDickey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the rule for `string-literal` in `lex.rkt` to:

```
[string-literal
   (:: #\" (:* char-literal1) #\")]
```

Note the added 1.

Comment: Since the question doesn't make sense without "grammar.rkt" and "lex.rkt" I think you should put them in your question, such that others can see the example.

Comment: good advice. Thanks very much! I think I made a silly mistake and asked a real silly question. sorry to bother.

Comment: The question is fine and I'm sure others would like to see how to use lex and ragg. It's a fine example, so that's why I asked you to put the code in the question.